# Error installing local tunnel

Tags: linux, rubygems, linux-mint, localtunnel

I get this error when installing localtunnel:

```
 sudo gem install localtunnel
[sudo] password for anr: 
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'localtunnel' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: localone, rack-tunnel
```

This is what I get when I `traceroute rubygems.org`:

```
   traceroute rubygems.org
   traceroute to rubygems.org (54.245.255.174), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
   1  192.168.100.1 (192.168.100.1)  2.882 ms  2.868 ms  3.900 ms
   2  dsl-ap-static-001.92.144.59.airtelbroadband.in (59.144.92.1)  22.183 ms  27.974 ms  27.970 ms
   3  ABTS-AP-Static-250.240.169.122.airtelbroadband.in (122.169.240.250)  23.142 ms  27.824 ms  31.209 ms
   4  125.16.7.125 (125.16.7.125)  31.243 ms  33.142 ms  37.945 ms
   5  182.79.255.33 (182.79.255.33)  334.176 ms  341.682 ms  347.246 ms
   6  nyiix-peering.amazon.com (198.32.160.64)  349.918 ms  293.726 ms  293.576 ms
   7  178.236.3.179 (178.236.3.179)  293.436 ms  299.831 ms  298.774 ms
   8  178.236.3.189 (178.236.3.189)  323.077 ms  319.980 ms 178.236.3.187 (178.236.3.187)  341.363 ms
   9  72.21.222.246 (72.21.222.246)  340.243 ms 72.21.222.232 (72.21.222.232)  342.429 ms  344.028 ms
   10  205.251.232.103 (205.251.232.103)  326.301 ms  334.583 ms 205.251.232.105 (205.251.232.105)  354.295 ms
   11  205.251.232.207 (205.251.232.207)  340.857 ms 205.251.232.213 (205.251.232.213)  349.718 ms 205.251.232.207 (205.251.232.207)  340.789 ms
   12  205.251.230.127 (205.251.230.127)  342.020 ms  323.848 ms  321.291 ms
   13  ec2-50-112-0-141.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (50.112.0.141)  334.590 ms ec2-50-112-0-207.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (50.112.0.207)  326.941 ms  324.361 ms
   14  * * *
   15  * * *
   16  * * *
   17  * * *
   18  * * *
   19  * * *
   20  * * *
   21  * * *
   22  * * *
   23  * * *
   24  * * *
   25  * * *
   26  * * *
   27  * * *
   28  * * *
   29  * * *
   30  * * *
```

I have also tried installing with a few proxies as suggested at askubuntu.